# Extracting table from a PDF table without vertical lines

Tags: pdf, tabula, python-camelot

I want to extract the table from PDF files that look like the following image:
[image]

The PDF file contains text and is not a scanned image. I have been trying to use [Camelot](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues) with no success. The `lattice` flavour doesn't work because there are no vertical lines and the `stream` flavour can't properly separate the rows. I played around with `row_tol` but because the rows have different heights it didn't work on all rows.

Is there a way to use the `lattice` method but consider the column separators for the vertical lines? Or is there another way of extracting the table?

Comment: You're going to have an exceptionally hard time finding **any** PDF parser that will be able to make sense of your table because the text in the cells is vertically centered and there is no gap between the rows. I suggest offshore rekeying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your Tables allways follow the same Layout/Logic. But if they do you can try out Poppler and use the Layout aware text conversion and manually parse it into csv or some other format.

PDF is a really ugly format for tabular data.

Comment: I have tried out Poppler, but unfortunately because of the vertical alignment of my tables the extracted text is all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Make a try with PDFplumber in python. Use extract_tables(vertical_strategy="text") . But I am not sure for accurate result because of the line with "Note" in the table.